# Does the parameter options.num-l2caches in gem5 have effect on hit_rate?

Tags: gem5

I am new to Gem5 simulator. The option in Gem5--options.py--num-l2caches does not have an effect on hit_rate.

In my experiment, I  added the 'option --l2cache' and modified the parameter: 'option --num-l2caches'. After modified the L2 cache number, I run the parsec benchmark and get the stats.txt. I used either the classic model or the general model.

```
./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/ruby_fs.py -n 1 --script=./ benchmark/Script/bodytrack_5c_simsmall.rcs --caches --l2cache --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU --num-l2caches=1
```

--num-l2caches could be 1 and 2.

But when I compare some parameters in stats.txt between two different l2 cache number, such as 'hit_rate'. I found this parameter in two files is the same. The result looks like the second L2 cache doesn't connect to architecture. Does it mean the option.num-l2caches have no effect on hit_rate?

Therefore, I want to know :

**1. What the meaning of --num-l2caches?**

**2. How could I make the option.--num-l2caches effective ?**

**3. Does the number of l2caches only support the power of two?**

Comment: I have never used this option, but a simple grep showed that it is only used in some ruby configurations and therefore will never modify results of ARM, unless you create your own configuration that uses it (the parameter num-l2caches is stored in options.num_l2caches). Check the existing configurations that use it and learn how to apply for your use case.
"grep -nr num_l2cache configs/" shows that the following files use it:
configs/ruby/MESI_Three_Level.py, configs/ruby/MOESI_CMP_directory.py,
configs/ruby/MOESI_CMP_token.py, configs/ruby/MESI_Two_Level.py

Comment: @DanielCarvalho It was quite insightful, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I used X86_MESI_Two_Level  build_options to check out the hit_rate between **--num_l2caches=2** and **--num_l2caches=3**. Unfortunately, I find in **--num_l2caches=3**, the third L2 cache access_number, miss_number, and hit_number are all zero. Why?

Comment: No idea. May be a bug, or an undocumented feature; as I said, I've never used this option. You can try asking the same questions in Gem5's user mailing list to see if anyone has ever used it, but you will likely end up hacking your way into Gem5 expertise :)

Comment: @DanielCarvalho Thanks again!